# Constructing a bounded smooth function with fixed derivatives.

Tags: analysis, functions

I am currently trying to construct a smooth function defined on $\left[-1,1 \right] $with the following properties:

1. $f\left(0 \right) =0$
2. $f^\prime\left(0 \right) =1$
3. $\left|f\left(x\right) \right| < k $ for some positive real number $k$

I have tried using the function of the form $\left(x + C \rho_{x_0} \left(x\right) \right) $, as well as the form
$\left(x + C x\rho_{x_0} \left(x\right) \right) $, with $\rho_{x_0}\left(x\right)=\begin{cases} 
e^\left(-\frac{1}{\left(x-x_0\right)^2} \right), &\text{when } x^2>x_0^2\\
0, &\text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}$

However, the function I constructed fails to satisfy the third condition when $k<1 $, no matter how I chose the coefficient of $\rho _{x_0} $ and the value of $ x_0$.

What I would like to know is that if there is a construction of such function, and is such function constructed in the way I have shown.

Comment: Idea: Try to use the function $$xe^{1-\frac{1}{1-(x/c)^2}},$$ for $|x|<c$ and 0 elsewhere, where $c$ is a parameter at your disposal.

Comment: That works perfectly well! Thank you. (By the way, is it possible for you to tell me how you figured out this function?)

Comment: isn't your third condition just saying $f$ is bounded on $[-1,1]$? Then it's trivially satisfied by $f(x)=x$.

Answer (score 1):

I'll post an answer, since you've checked that it works out :)

How to construct such a function? Well, the condition $f(0)=0$ and $f'(0)=1$ say your functions looks like $x$ near the origin. The third condition says that $f$ shouldn't be allowed to grow too much, which we can always guarantee if we cut off $x$ sufficiently close near the origin, this suggests we use a bump function and multiply $x$ by it.

Now the product rule, and the second condition, tell us that such a bump must satisfy $g(0)=1$ (the other term is always killed by $x$) and so we look at $e^{1-1/(1-x^2)}$ (note that this is just $e$ times the standard bump function, the $e$ factor is there to guarantee it's 1 at 0) which satisfies this, but the support condition is not, so we scale it horizontally by $c$ to get $e^{1-\frac{1}{1-(x/c)^2}}$ for $|x|<c$.

Comment: That explains a lot, thank you very much! (Sorry for my late reply.)